# How can I extract package source from Oracle database?

Tags: oracle10g

Can any one please help me to extract a package from Oracle database schema through Command Line Interface.

Answer (score 4):

Use DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL:

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (
    object_type IN VARCHAR2,
    name IN VARCHAR2,
    schema IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    version IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'COMPATIBLE',
    model IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'ORACLE',
    transform IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'DDL')
RETURN CLOB;
```