# oracle package referring old schema after migration to new schema

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, impdp

I used [impdp](/questions/tagged/impdp) to import dump from `OLD_SCHEMA` to `NEW_SCHEMA`. All packages look fine except 10 packages, the error is that they refer to old schema i.e., the table names in them are being affixed with `OLD_SCHEMA`. i.e., `OLD_SCHEMA.table_name`. I checked synonyms they look same as in correct packages.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Yes, you open up the package, change the old schema name to the new schema name and then recompile the package... if there's only 10 should take less than a minute. Or, is this something you're having to do automatically and regularly?

Comment: Or remove the schema qualifications completely if they aren't needed - if the tables are in the same schema as the packages anyway. That would stop it being a problem again in the future. Did you use the `REMAP_SCHEMA` option, out of interest?

Comment: I recompiled the package and it resolved the issue. Thanks for help Ben and Alex

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you have several possibilities, depending on what you need.

- use the `REMAP_SCHEMA` option in your import command:

  ```
   REMAP_SCHEMA=source_schema:target_schema
  ```
- remove schema names from your packages and use synonyms only. This limits you to have objects with same names on different schemas.
- have a script to extract source from all packages, rename schema with some regular expression, and re-injects the source by recompiling the code on the new database; to extract the source, use [`dbms_metadata.get_clob`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457849/how-can-i-extract-package-source-from-oracle-database); then it gets a little trickier to the part where you have to change text in the `CLOB`, but it's fun.